# PageReference setRedirect not working!

Tags: pagereference

We are using lightning experience - servivce console.
I am using following code to redirect the page flow to an error page for certain profiles.

I can see in the debug logs that the PageReference is getting correctly set to the error page , but the page redirection does not work

```
Profile[] profileName = [SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :Userinfo.getProfileId() ];
if(profileName[0].Name!='Profile 1')
        {
            redirectByProfile();
        }
```

redirect method

```
 public PageReference redirectByProfile()
    {

        PageReference pageRef ;
        pageRef=Page.vfErrorPage;
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
```

debug logs

> [559]|DEBUG|pageRef++++System.PageReference[/apex/vferrorpage]
>   09:23:29.0 (166664283)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[559]|System.debug(ANY)
>   09:23:29.0 (166669547)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[560] 09:23:29.0
>   (166675865)|METHOD_EXIT|[117]|01pq0000000d5sC|CaseDetailsPDFController.redirectByProfile()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're throwing away the return value of `redirectByProfile()` when you call it in your first snippet. You have to return the `PageReference` as the result of a Visualforce action method in order for a redirect to take place.